# Installing emacs on debian stable stretch

Tags: debian, emacs

I have a user who needs emacs (emacs-x11, preferred) on Debian stable.  I found the following https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSnapshotAndDebian which mentions to "packages built directly from Emacs git master here: http://emacs.ganneff.de/"  - this sounds like what I need, but I am unsure the commands to install it.  We have tried flatpak but found that the window as rendered by xming would jump around and flatpak's static library integration prevented use of our in-house software development tools.  Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you ruled out using debian packages `emacs25` or `emacs25-lucid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 4 different emacs packages available in Debian Stretch and you really want to compile emacs from source?

- [emacs](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/emacs) (GTK+ GUI support)
- [emacs25-lucid](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/emacs25-lucid) (GUI based on Lucid toolkit)
- [emacs25-nox](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/emacs25-nox) (no GUI)
- [xemacs21](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/editors/xemacs21)

As far as i know they all have gui support except for emacs25-nox.

To install the latest package, run as root:

```
# optional: fetch the latest package index files
apt-get update 
# replace with the package you want to install: emacs, emacs25-lucid, emacs25-nox or xemacs21
apt-get install emacs
```

If the user really wants his own version, then tell him he should compile it himself. That's not your job as administrator.